# Encontrar a maior sequencia usando Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
import collections
num = int(input('Digite um número inteiro: '))    #Inputar número inteiro
binario = bin(num)[2:]     #Cortar o 0b
sequence = binario
collection = collections.Counter(sequence)
print('O número binário de {} é {}'.format(num,binario))
print('A sequência que mais temos é {}'.format(collection.most_common(2)))
```

Ele já me mostra quantas vezes aparece o número 1 e 0 em cada número binário; Porém agora preciso que ele encontre a maior sequencia de 0 por exemplo em 200 binário é 11001**000** no caso a maior sequencia de 0 são 3; Queria resolver isso no próprio programa.

Comment: Já tentou alguma coisa? Qual foi o resultado?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
max(binario.split('1'), key=len)
```

Desta forma eu crio um `array` separando por 1, depois utilizo a função `max` para pegar o maior `len`, resultando na maior sequência de zeros.

Utilizando o seu código:

```
import collections
num = int(input('Digite um número inteiro: '))    #Inputar número inteiro
binario = bin(num)[2:]     #Cortar o 0b
sequence = binario
collection = collections.Counter(sequence)
print('O número binário de {} é {}'.format(num,binario))
print('A sequência que mais temos é {}'.format(collection.most_common(2)))
print('A maior sequência de 0 é {}'.format(max(binario.split('1'), key=len)))
```

Resultado:

```
Digite um número inteiro: 200
O número binário de 200 é 11001000
A sequência que mais temos é [('0', 5), ('1', 3)]
A maior sequência de 0 é 000
```

**Update**

Uma nova forma para responder o que foi solicitado nos comentários.
Para mostrar a maior quantidade de dígitos 0 repetidos, coloque a função `len`, assim ele pega a quantidade de dígitos da `string`.

```
len(max(binario.split('1'), key=len)))
```

Utilizando o seu código:

```
import collections
num = int(input('Digite um número inteiro: '))    #Inputar número inteiro
binario = bin(num)[2:]     #Cortar o 0b
sequence = binario
collection = collections.Counter(sequence)
print('O número binário de {} é {}'.format(num,binario))
print('A sequência que mais temos é {}'.format(collection.most_common(2)))
print('A maior sequência de 0 é {}'.format(len(max(binario.split('1'), key=len))))
```

Resultado:

```
Digite um número inteiro: 200
O número binário de 200 é 11001000
A sequência que mais temos é [('0', 5), ('1', 3)]
A maior sequência de 0 é 3
```

Comment: O código funciona muito bem, porém ai como eu faria ao invés de aparecer inúmeros zeros no resultado ele apresenta-se um exemplo: a maior sequência de 0 é 5.

Comment: Não entendi, acho que sua mensagem esta faltando algo

Comment: Então ao invés de apresentar o resultado 0000 apresenta o resultado 4; Ao invés dele apresentar em zeros apresentar já na unidade no caso contar quantos seriam.

Comment: Editei e coloquei o resultado, eu ainda não entendi o que você quis dizer, você quer que seja mostrado o índice?

Comment: Então é que no caso neste momento do código: A maior sequência de 0 é 000; Gostaria que aparece-se A maior sequência é 3 (no caso 3 x 000)

Comment: Editei, acredito que agora esta do forma que você quer

Comment: Perfeito era isso mesmo, muito agradecido!

Comment: Cool! (+1). Outra variante: `max(map(len,b.split('1')))`